# Vue data objects are not being reactive when triggered by @change

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, quasar

Creating a page that will display the contents of an uploaded file.  But I do not understand why `msg` and `show` data parameters are not being updated when it is triggered via `@change`.  I need both of these parameters to only be updated if file upload was successful so that is why I placed these inside the `onload` function lambda:

```
reader.onload = function(e) {
  this.msg = e.target.result;
  this.show = true;
  console.log(this.msg);
}
```

Also notice that `console.log(this.msg)` logs the file content correctly.
So why is it that the child does not get these changes?

I also tried setting them via a button click and it works fine.

Here is my code (App.vue):

```
<template>
  <div id="q-app">
    <router-view></router-view>
    <input type="file" ref="file" @change="changeViaUpload">

    <br><br>
    <button @click="changeViaButton">Update data via Button</button>

    <hello :show=show :msg=msg></hello>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import hello from '../components/Hello.vue'

export default {
  name: "app",
  components:{
        hello
    },
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "",
      show: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeViaUpload(ev) {
      const file = ev.target.files[0];
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(e) {
        this.msg = e.target.result;
        this.show = true;
        console.log(this.msg);
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
    },
    changeViaButton() {
      this.msg = "Message has been changed via button";
      this.show = true;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And here is my `Hello.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="show">
    <!-- <div> -->
        [Hello.vue] This div will be shown if boolean show is true
        <br>
        {{ msg }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['msg','show'],
    data() {
    return {
    };
  },
  methods: {
  }
};
</script>
```

[CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-quasar-template-j47j9)

Help please! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**this** is not the Vue instance in your code inside the **FileReader's onload** function. When you write:

```
reader.onload = function() {}
```

**this** becomes the **onload** inside that function (its scope changes). Try

```
const self = this
```

before **reader.onload** and use **self** inside your onload function, or try using a **fat arrow function**

```
reader.onload = (e) => {}
```

**fat arrow functions** (or just simply arrow functions) have a lexical **this**, meaning the scope does not change inside such functions.

*Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions*

Answer (score 0):

So I am now able to make it work. I modified `changeViaUpload()` to use:

```
var vm = this;
```

and update the param via: `vm.msg`

Snippet:

```
    changeViaUpload(ev) {
      const file = ev.target.files[0];
      const reader = new FileReader();
      var vm = this;

      reader.onload = function(e) {
        vm.msg = e.target.result;
        vm.show = true;
        console.log(vm.msg);
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
    },
```